# What does "(void)temp;" statement mean?

Tags: c

I was going through some code and came across a piece of code which was like this:-

```
void func(int a)
{
   int temp;
       ...
       ....
   temp=a;
   (void)temp;
}
```

What does the temp variable do here? If I compile it using -Wall option, I do not get any compilation error or warning either. Please help me understand this code style.
Thanks.

Comment: In the actual snippet you post, the `(void)temp` looks very odd indeed.

Comment: What NPE said. This is a situation where you really do want the compiler to warn you about that, so you can remove the unnecessary local.

Answer (score 6):

It means that the value of `temp` is otherwise unused, and the optimizing compiler warns about it (variable is set but not used), but by including the `(void)temp;`, you (currently) get away without the warning from the compiler.  The line generates no code as well as no compiler warning.

Given the source code:

```
extern void func(int a);
void func(int a)
{
   int temp;
   temp = a;
   //(void)temp;
}
```

GCC 4.8.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.4 gives the warning for the code:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -c void.c
void.c: In function ‘func’:
void.c:4:8: warning: variable ‘temp’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    int temp;
        ^
$
```

With the comment marker removed (so `(void)temp;` is compiled), the compilation generates no warning.

---

This is clearly example code distilled from some larger context (an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — thank you for producing one!).  There may be a number of reasons (of greater or lesser validity) why the code appears.  Often, it will be because there is conditionally compiled code after the assignment to `temp` which will use the assigned value.  Instead of being an assignment of a function parameter, it will often be the result of a function call:

```
void func(int a)
{
    int temp;
    ...
    temp = some_function(a);
#if defined(SOMETHING_OR_OTHER)
    ...do stuff with temp...
#else
    (void)temp;
#endif
}
```

This notation keeps the single function call, but avoids complaints from the compiler when `SOMETHING_OR_OTHER` is not defined.

Comment: I tried gcc -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -c void.c on my Ubuntu machine which uses gcc version (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2 but I did not get any error or warning.  Yes, you are correct. temp collects the return value of a system call namely write(). But the func() itself does not have a conditional compilation within it. Thanks for the pointer though.I will keep that in mind while browsing the code.

Comment: The 'set but unused' warning was added in GCC 4.6.0; it was not in GCC 4.5.x.  I was able to test 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6.0, 4.7.0, 4.7.1, 4.8.1 (I keep copies of them — but the 4.4.2 instance is bust, missing a library).

Answer (score 0):

Cheat the compiler: Pretend as `temp` was used, but in fact do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It evaluates the expression `temp` (a simple but still a valid expression) and tells the compiler that the result of the expression is discarded by casting the result of the expression to `void` (which means "no type").